# what does it mean by 'TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple'?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import time
import random

# pygame window initialisation
pygame.init()

#declare the colors using their RBG colors
orangecolor = (253, 123, 7)
blackcolor = (0, 0, 0)
redcolor = (213, 50 , 80)
greencolor = (0, 255, 0)
bluecolor = (50, 153, 213)

#Dislay window's width and height
display_width = 600
display_height = 600
dis = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")
snake_block = 10
game_over = False
while not game_over:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == quit:
            game_over = True
    pygame.draw.rect(dis,orangecolor[200,150,snake_block, snake_block])
pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

the terminal displays an error for the line `pygame.draw.rect(dis,orangecolor[200,150,snake_block, snake_block])` is there any error in the code? I use visual studio 2019 community version

Comment: It is a typo. There is missing a `,` after `orangecolor`  in `pygame.draw.rect(dis,orangecolor[200,150,snake_block, snake_block])`

Comment: Your variable `orangecolor = (253, 123, 7)` is a tuple. with 3 values. What are you trying to do in this statement `pygame.draw.rect(dis,orangecolor[200,150,snake_block, snake_block])`. You cannot redefine `orangecolor`

Comment: thanks a lot  you have really helped me out

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo. There is missing a `,` after `orangecolor`:

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(dis,orangecolor[200,150,snake_block, snake_block])`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(dis, orangecolor, [200, 150, snake_block, snake_block])
```